# How to add controls to parent form from a looped over child component?

Tags: angular

I have a parent component with a form defined (mainForm). I have to loop over an array and add controls to the mainForm(or recognize controls from mainForm) so I can subscribe to changes in these forms. Child form can't be a FormArray as it can have elements that other child forms don't. So, I set it up like this as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54055399/1456913).

App/Parent Component:

```
<form [formGroup]="mainForm">
  <p>Main</p>
  <input type="text" formControlName="mainInput" />
  <div formGroupName="childForm" class="childForm">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let i of [1, 2, 3, 4]">
      <app-child key="{{ 'childTest' + i }}"></app-child>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</form>
```

App/Parent Component TS:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  mainForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mainForm = this.fb.group({
      mainInput: [''],
      childForm: this.fb.group({
        childInput: [''],
        childTest1: this.fb.group({
          someTextBox: [''],
          otherTextBox: [''],
        }),
        childTest2: this.fb.group({
          someTextBox: [''],
        }),
        childTest3: this.fb.group({
          someTextBox: [''],
        }),
        childTest4: this.fb.group({
          someTextBox: [''],
        }),
      }),
    });

    this.mainForm.get('childForm').valueChanges.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      console.log(this.mainForm);
    });
  }
}
```

Child HTML:

```
<div formGroupName="{{ key }}" class="childKey">
  <p>{{ key }}</p>
  <input type="text" formControlName="someTextBox" />
</div>
```

Child TS:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  viewProviders: [
    { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupDirective },
  ],
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  subSubForm: FormGroup;
  @Input() key: string;
  constructor(private fgd: FormGroupDirective, private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    let name = 'childTest' + this.key;
    this.subSubForm = this.fgd.form.get('childForm') as FormGroup;
    let form = this.fb.group({});
    this.subSubForm.addControl('childTest' + this.key, form);
  }
}
```

However, when I try this, I get the errors
`Cannot find control with name: 'childTest1'` and
`Cannot find control with path: 'childTest1 -> someTextBox'`

How can I fix this or is there a better way to do this?

## [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-r4svjq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts)

Comment: I found the answer in this blog post: https://blog.profanis.me/blog/reactive-forms-in-parent-child-components 
Here is the solved StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vbhwdc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.html
Essentially, I was missing the hierarchy of the formgroup/formgroupname that angular was expecting.